# Google Analytics Active Page

Tags: google-analytics

In the new version of Google Analytics under Top Active Pages I see an url (or similar)

/1.php/Oi8vd3d3/LnBpbmtm/aW5lYXJ0/LmNvbS8_/3D/b0/

and this url stays up for several minutes (the one above has been 1/2 hr so far) which should mean they are active. Yet if I add this to the end of my sites url it comes back with a 404 error page.

Any idea what someone is doing/looking for?

Comment: Try to be a bit more specific.